# How to increase query timeout in oracle source in SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am new to SSIS. I am trying to load data from an oracle database using the Oracle source in visual studio 2019. I am able to successfully connect to the database however when I place my script command in the Oracle source editor in Visual studio and click Preview, I get the error `HYT00 query timeout expired`.

I have been googling for hours to find where to update this timeout but that option is not available in the properties.

**Oracle Connection Manager**

[image]

**Oracle Source Custom Properties**

Below are the custom properties. As you can see there is no info about query timeout. Appreciate assistance

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use OFFSET FETCH Feature for  loading large volumes of Data using limited resources with SSIS ?